# How can we set timeOut if dont know how long page loading will take

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've made script  which change information from different site, its occure when i click on button, sometimes it takes 1-2 seconds to find info and display it, sometimes 10 or more seconds. i made a script which change some table rows etc in timeOut 5 seconds, how can i set timeOut if i dont know how long this search will go

```
$("div.dreamcast input.btn").click(function() {

    $.ajax({    
        success: function () {  
            setTimeout(function() {
                //i want to change results information here
                $('table.itt_results tbody tr:first th:contains("etc")').hide();

                },
                5000 //timeout 5s
            );
});
```

Comment: Your `setTimeout` won't run until after the AJAX call is successfully completed anyway, so I'm not sure what it's doing there at all. Are you familiar with how the `success` callback is supposed to work?

Comment: Once you are in the success method, it is done, you don't need the setTimeout. The data is ready to be used.

Comment: You don't really need `setTimeout` since the AJAX `success` callback won't fire until the request is finished anyway.

Comment: ok gonna try it without timeOut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the succes function of the jQuery ajax call, the code gets executed as soon as the AJAX call has been successful. This way, you don't have to know how long it takes, it will always be fine.

So no need for a setTimeout here.

Answer (score 0):

The success method will only be executed when you have the result so you don't need the timeout function there.

Answer (score 0):

The success function will only run when the ajax function has finished successfully. There's no need to guess how long it will take.